# Revised: Can premade Doxygen documentation be added into a SharePoint Communication Site so that SP pages can link to relevant parts?

Tags: sharepoint, doxygen

Revised: The original request specified adding Doxygen generated html pages to a SharePoint Communication site.  However, Doxygen can generate documentation in other formats besides html.  Although I am not as acquainted with using Doxygen documentation in the other formats, it might be that some of these alternate formats have an advantage of being more self-contained and therefore more compatible with SharePoint.  I am open to considering them, if someone can propose an effective arrangement.  The key desirable feature would still be some level of ability to link to (or at least position to) a relevant point in the documentation (e.g. bring up the documentation for a particular class).  A solution that just presents the documentation as a (potentially very long) "book" to be read sequentially would be an inferior solution.

The original problem description in terms of html pages follows below:

Doxygen can produce an integrated set of html pages to document code. The pages in a Microsoft SharePoint Communication Site are able to link to externally available web pages and potentially could link to the Doxygen generated pages, if they are hosted elsewhere.

However, that would mean that one would need to separately control access to the site where the Doxygen pages are hosted, and make sure that everyone who has access to the Communication Site and who should be able to follow the links also separately has been given permission at the other hosting site.

The question is whether there is a way to effectively host the Doxygen pages inside the Communication Site so that those with access to the site also have access to the Doxygen pages and the links work seamlessly.

I made some attempts to use the html pages after uploading them into folder hierarchy in a Document library.  However, I couldn't find a way that could then display them correctly in the browser.  Some methods seemed to strip the pages down to the bare html of the main page without correctly applying style sheets, etc.  (The Doxygen generated pages include file types .css and .js files, as well as .html, .png, and .svg.)  This didn't work even though the Sync was reported to be complete.

When I direct a browser (e.g. Microsoft Edge) to the same pages in the corresponding folders on my laptop, the same browser renders the pages just fine.  (This is accessing them as files from disk rather than via https over the web, but the page and folder contents are exactly the same.) This browser can work with and render these Doxygen html pages, but it's not working (yet?) to try to get at them inside the Communication Site.

Thanks in advance for insights about how to make Communication Site pages link to premade html (and css and js and png) pages added into a SharePoint Communication Site.

p.s. If you want to see if you have a solution to this puzzle, the Doxygen wizard application makes it easy to generate some Doxygen html documentation pages for any application you have.  Try it with the navigation panel turned on for the generated pages.  Then you will see if your approach can render the correct page behavior even when linked to the pages inside the Communication Site.  Thanks.